# how to do bit shifts and masks in haskell?

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a routine to determine whether the high 16 bits of a 32-bit integer have more bits set, or the low bits.

In C, I would write this:

```
bool more_high_bits(int a) {
  if ((a >> 16) == 0) return false;    // no high bits
  if ((a & 0xFFFF) == 0) return true;  // no low bits

  // clear one high bit and one low bit, and ask again
  return more_high_bits(a&(a - 0x10001));
}
```

So in Haskell, I'm trying this:

```
more_high_bits a=if (a `shiftR` 16) /= 0 then 0 else
                 if ((.&.) a 65535) /= 0 then 1 else
                 more_high_bits((.&.) a (a-65537))
```

But it just times out.

What am I doing wrong?  What's the more idiomatic way to do this?  Please don't code away the shift or the & because I'd like to know how I "should" be using these.

Addendum: I tried this code out on an haskell compiler:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_haskell_online.php

```
import Data.Bits

g a=if (a `shiftR` 16) == 0 then 0 else
    if ((.&.) a 65535) == 0 then 1 else
    g((.&.) a (a-65537))

main = print (g(237))
```

But it tells me "No instance for (Bits a0) arising from a use of 'g'
The type variable 'a0' is ambiguous"

What is "a0"??

Comment: You changed a `==` into a `/=` -- obviously your code won't work. (Haskell's `/=` is C's `!=`, for reference! You just want `==`.)

Comment: What type did you intend 237 to be?  There are many possible types.

Comment: Try something like: `main = print (moreHighBits (70000 :: Int))` -- the type checker can't infer which type to use, as `.&.` and friends apply to all `Bits a` types.

Comment: You could also limit the function by adding a [signature](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_signature) such as `moreHighBits :: Int -> Bool` above your definition. In Haskell, function names are in `camelCase` by convention, and return `False`/`True` (of type `Bool`), not `0`/`1`.

Comment: I corrected the /= to be ==, thanks.  Also, I know conceptually this is a boolean return, but for my purposes I actually need the result to be 0 or 1, since this algorithm eventually needs to be generalized to identify which of 4 regions of an integer has the highest # of bits set.

Comment: @jorgbrown As an aside on design: I don't think "I want to generalize this algorithm to identify one region out of four" implies "I need the result to be 0 or 1". This function can still return a `Bool` just fine, even if you want to use it as a component of your other function; and the other function probably shouldn't be returning a number anyway, but a value of a custom type like `data Region = VeryHigh | High | Low | VeryLow`.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes but I don't want to call this function from another function; I want to change this function into the other function.  You are right that it should probably be returning an enumerated type, except that it would be nice to be able to retrieve the section of the integer with the most bits set simply by right-shifting. It's a long story...

Comment: [Related from codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46228/27529)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a pretty direct translation of your C code to Haskell:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits

more_high_bits :: Word32 -> Bool
more_high_bits a
    | (a `shiftR` 16) == 0 = False
    | (a .&. 0xFFFF)  == 0 = True
    | otherwise            = more_high_bits (a .&. (a - 0x10001))
```

Your attempt has `/=` where the C version has `==`, which inverts the condition.

`a0` is the type variable that the type checker automatically created for your use of `g 237`. It doesn't know which type you mean because `237` could be any numeric type at all, and `g` works with all numbers that support bitwise operations and equality. The list of types you could have meant includes (but is not limited to) `Int`, `Integer`, `Word`, ...

Comment: I'd rename the function to `moreHighBits`, following the [Haskell naming conventions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Programming_guidelines#Naming_Conventions).

Comment: I'm not sure if the guards really make sense here - seems like this should just be a boolean expression.

Comment: @Cubic I wanted to follow the look and feel of the C function.

Comment: Thanks, @melpomene. For what it's worth, I had to shrink this down for a competition, and it became ...

``m a|a`shiftR`16<1=0|a.&.65535<1=1|0<1=m(a.&.(a-65537))``